# Is it possible to specify searched fields when an index alias is created with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, alias

is it possible to specify searched fields when an index alias is created?

Here is my request to create an index

`curl -X POST --header 'content-type: application/json' --data-raw '{"actions": [{"add":{"index":"product","alias": "products"}}]}' http://localhost:9200/_aliases`

When I use the original index for searching, the results are filtered on the fields I specified in the query. The same search query based on the alias does the search on all fields. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filtered aliases](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-filtered-aliases/).

```
PUT /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "my_index",
        "alias": "my_alias",
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "FIELD": "VALUE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```